# CordovaApp.pfx create .aetx token?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Can the `CordovaApp.pfx` in `res\native\windows` be used to create a .aetx token?

Signing is handled automatically with VS2015 community + Cordova when deploying a package for release.

Sample `CordovaApp.pfx` https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta/tree/master/res/native/windows

Here's instructions on how to create .aetx from .pfx = [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx)

All I get when trying to convert is: `Invalid certificate or password`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `.aetx` token can only be created if a Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate from Symantec Corp has been purchased.  Without the certificate, AetGenerator.exe is unable to create an `.aetx` from the `.pfx`.

Explanation on how to use AETX and Mobile Certificates.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296515.aspx

Download Root Certificates
https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO20770&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US

Instructions on how to sign an app
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735576(v=vs.105).aspx

I hope this helps!